# Ionic: unable to access some routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using AngularJS with ui-router (Ionic). My app divided into some modules. Each module has own routing file (routes.js).
On my navigation page I have some links. When I click on some of this links url in browser changes, but content in browser doesn't change (controller doesn't being loaded).

Each module defined like this.

```
angular.module('app.module.user').config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('in.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: './templates/user/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController as login'
  })...
```

I'm trying to debug route change using $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess, but with no luck.

Comment: Does the "in.login" state have an ancestor?  Also, is the path to the template correct?

Answer (score -1):

I have similar issues with dot notation at states. I avoid dot notation and my app work well. Try this:

```
$stateProvider.state('in_login', {…})
```

Ciao
Ralf